# Testing update view: how to pass.change value data in updateview with form?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I try to write testcase for one of my view that use a form.
views.py

```
def parametrage(request,pk):
    
    parametrage = get_object_or_404(Parametrage, asp_par_cle = pk)
    form = ParametrageForm(request, data=request.POST or None, instance = parametrage)
    print('form.data',form.data)

    if form.is_valid():
        parametrage = form.save()
        parametrage.opr_nom = request.user.username
        parametrage.opr_dat = timezone.now()
        form.save()

        return redirect('pharmacy:dashboard')

    return render(request, 'pharmacy/parametrage.html', {'form': form})
```

tests.py

```
class PharmacyParametrageTestCase(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        Parametrage.objects.create(asp_par_loc='TR',asp_par_ale=1,asp_par_con=8)
    
    def test_email_alert(self):
        instance = Parametrage.objects.get(asp_par_cle=1)
        data = json.dumps({"asp_par_ale":2,})
        response = self.client.post(reverse('pharmacy:parametrage', kwargs={'pk':1}),instance=instance, data=data, follow=True, content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200)
        self.assertEqual(Parametrage.objects.get(asp_par_cle=1).asp_par_ale,2)
```

The second assert failed because Parametrage instance is not updated.
form.is_valid() return False and form.errors do not return any error.
form.data is empty

obviously, I never change asp_par_ale value but don't know how to do that in tests.
I try to pass data but doesn't work neither
appreciate some help

Comment: Are you sure your form is valid ? Your code returns 200 in both cases i think. print **response.context['form']['errors']** for checking form errors in response in testcase

Comment: this make ``` KeyError: "Key 'errors' not found in 'ParametrageForm'. Choices are: asp_par_ale, asp_par_con, asp_par_loc, pays."``` but probably my form is not valid as it is not passing the form.is_valid() condition in view. But if I print(form.errors in views it is empty

Answer (score 0):

i found i guess, when you said, object is not updated, you spoke only about opr_dat and opr_dat ? You called form.save() twice. You have to call isntance save function :

```
def parametrage(request,pk):
    
    parametrage = get_object_or_404(Parametrage, asp_par_cle = pk)
    form = ParametrageForm(request, data=request.POST or None, instance = parametrage)
    print('form.data',form.data)

    if form.is_valid():
        parametrage = form.save(commit=False)
        parametrage.opr_nom = request.user.username
        parametrage.opr_dat = timezone.now()
        parametrage.save()

        return redirect('pharmacy:dashboard')

    return render(request, 'pharmacy/parametrage.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: inf fact, issue came from the fact that I did not correctly pass data to the view so that form was not bound (is_bound=False)

Comment: in all cases, opr_dat and opr_nom was never saved and your have twice objects saved for each call